# Слабая и сильная позиция

Tags: фонетика

**Второй** класс. Нужно найти орфограмму "согласный парный по глухости/звонкости".
Есть слово "вЕсти". В слове "вЕсти" звук [с] находится в слабой позиции по глухости/звонкости, т.к.
он стоит перед глухим парным, но значит ли это, что эту орфограмму нужно выписывать, мы же не можем сказать [везти], [весди]?

Comment: Скорее всего ВЕСТи́ - проводить, и ВЕЗТи́ - провозить. А не вЕсти - новости.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово ***вести*** (ведет)  произносится так:  ***ве(с)ти.***  Но точно также произносится слово ***везти*** (везет): ***ве(с)ти.***

В устной речи мы не различаем эти слова и поэтому не можем **без проверки** выбрать нужную  букву для звука в  слабой позиции. **Это орфограмма.**  Все буквы в слабых позициях являются орфограммами.

Смысл заданного слова  и подбор проверочного слова делается **по тексту:** везти (везет) пассажиров, вести (ведет) ребенка в сад.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149150/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.